# start a node.js service

Tags: node.js, blueimp

I am attempting to follow the setup instructions for the node.js service, blueimp-file-upload, found here:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup

Specifically, I'm working through these steps under **Using jQuery File Upload (UI version) with Node.js**:

> You can install the sample Node.js upload service on your server via npm:
>
> > npm install blueimp-file-upload-node
>
> You can start the service by running the following command:
>
> > ./node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js

I have completed the first step (the installation of npm), but I do not understand what is meant by running the "./node_modules/..." command. It is not considered valid syntax in Windows' command prompt, nor the Node.js-specific command prompt, even when prefixed with npm.

Answer (score 4):

You have to run it in Node.JS. In the command line, type:

```
node node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js
```

Comment: No. Most Node.JS web servers only start in your current command prompt and stay there, logging things as you use 'em.

Comment: Oh, okay. It's my understanding that this module is intended to run on a web server so that it can be used to facilitate file uploading. Wouldn't that indicate that it needs to be able to run in the background as a service?

Comment: Probably yes; however, I would run it by myself everytime I was going to work on the plugin. This is because I would want to check the server log and it would be another useless process to kill when it's without usage.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help; I can't upvote your answer because I don't have sufficient reputation, but I greatly appreciate it!